# Binding HTML to property (Vue.js)

Tags: vue.js

How can I bind HTML to a Vue component property?

In my PHP script I have:

```
$html = '<div>some text</div>';

$box = "<box_includes
html_text='$html'
></box_includes>";
```

In my vue template:

```
<template id="template_box_includes">
{{ html_text }}
</template>
```

But in my browser I see all the text, including the tags, It's being recognized as a text:

```
<div>some text</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT 2019:**

Below answer [is outdated](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#HTML-Interpolation-removed) as stated by @devman in the comments. Please use `v-html` instead:

```
<template v-html="html_text"></template>
```

---

**Older Answer**

In Vue JS, the use of the double braces are escaping HTML. You need to use three to avoid escaping html like so:

```
<template id="template_box_includes">
{{{ html_text }}}
</template>
```

You can learn more on this page of the documentation: http://vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

I hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, I've must have googled it wrongly. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: attention: this doesn't seem to work anymore. `v-html` works though